# Pass fileset into XSLT task

Tags: xslt, ant

Here is the situation.
The output of the transformation have to be based on the number and the names of the files into the fileset.
The fileset looks like this:

```
        <fileset dir="lpf-version-34.0/" casesensitive="yes">
            <include name="*/*-uniques.xml"/>
        </fileset>
```

Suppose I have three files in this fileset:

> lpf-version-34.0/1/tod-uniques.xml
>
> lpf-version-34.0/2/tod-uniques.xml
>
> lpf-version-34.0/3/tod-uniques.xml

I want somehow these files to be passed (as parameters for example) to the `xsl` file, so I can then produce output like this:

```
<files>
    <file path="lpf-version-34.0/1/tod-uniques.xml"/>
    <file path="lpf-version-34.0/2/tod-uniques.xml"/>
    <file path="lpf-version-34.0/3/tod-uniques.xml"/>
</files>
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use [pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual-1.9.x/Tasks/pathconvert.html) task to concat all the files of the fileset and store it into a property. After that, you can pass that property as parameter to the xsl stylesheet and process it in the xsl. Below an example that build the parameter to pass to the xsl :

```
<fileset dir="lpf-version-34.0/" casesensitive="yes" id="lpf-files.id">
        <include name="*/*-uniques.xml"/>
</fileset>
<pathconvert pathsep="," property="lpflist" refid="lpf-files.id"/>
<xslt in="somefile.xml" style="style.xsl" out="result.xml">
    <param name="files" expression="${lpflist}"/>
</xslt>
```

Of course it assumes that your xsl file (style.xsl in that example) defines and handles properly the parameter `files`.

Answer (score 0):

In the following solution:

- Ant's [`<script>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) task uses JavaScript to generate XML from a `<fileset>`.
- The XML is passed as a string parameter to an XSLT stylesheet.
- The Saxon-B `saxon:parse` function converts the XML string into a proper XML node.
- The XSLT stylesheet inserts the XML node into a new XML document.

[Saxon-B](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) is an XSLT processor that has a handy function named [saxon:parse](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/parse.html):

> [saxon:parse] takes a single argument, a string containing the source text of a well-formed XML document. It returns the document node (root node) that results from parsing this text.

To use Saxon-B, download saxonb9-1-0-8j.zip from http://saxon.sourceforge.net/. Extract saxon9.jar from the downloaded Zip file into the directory with your build.xml file.

### in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theRoot/>
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="ant-xslt-call-with-xml-param" default="run" basedir=".">
    <target name="run">
        <!-- The fileset needs an "id" so the JavaScript can find it. -->
        <!-- -->
        <!-- Note: "dir" was "lpf-version-34.0" in the question. -->
        <!-- The JavaScript is simpler with "lpf-version-34.0" in the <include>. -->
        <fileset id="my-fileset" dir="${basedir}" casesensitive="yes">
            <include name="lpf-version-34.0/*/*-uniques.xml"/>
        </fileset>
        <script language="javascript">
        <![CDATA[
            // A bunch of XML infrastructure boilerplate.
            var docFactory = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            var docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            var tFactory = javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            var transformer = tFactory.newTransformer();
            transformer.setOutputProperty(
                javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
            var writer = new java.io.StringWriter();

            var doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            var filesElement = doc.createElement("files");
            doc.appendChild(filesElement);

            var fileSet = project.getReference( "my-fileset" );
            var ds = fileSet.getDirectoryScanner( project );
            var includes = ds.getIncludedFiles();
            for ( var i = 0; i < includes.length; i++ )
            {
                var filename = includes[i]
                var singleFileElement = doc.createElement("file");
                singleFileElement.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(filename));
                filesElement.appendChild(singleFileElement);
            }
            transformer.transform(
                new javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource(doc),
                new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(writer));
            var outputXml = writer.getBuffer().toString();

            project.setProperty( "fileset-xml", outputXml );
        ]]>
        </script>
        <xslt style="transform.xsl" in="in.xml" out="out.xml">
            <classpath location="saxon9.jar"/>
            <factory name="net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
            <param name="fileset-xml" expression="${fileset-xml}"/>
        </xslt>
    </target>
</project>
```

### transform.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:param name="fileset-xml"/>

    <xsl:template match="/theRoot">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="saxon:parse($fileset-xml)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Resulting XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<theRoot>
   <files>
      <file>lpf-version-34.0\1\tod-uniques.xml</file>
      <file>lpf-version-34.0\2\tod-uniques.xml</file>
      <file>lpf-version-34.0\3\tod-uniques.xml</file>
   </files>
</theRoot>
```

Comment: I get this error:
     [xslt] : Error! The first argument to the non-static Java function 'parse'
is not a valid object reference.

Comment: This is what I get from as a raw copy of `$fileset-xml` : 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vtd9WI81S4Yw__LwzuJoVCfHc4fmXpDrMh9ocGgjUjI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The error `"not a valid object reference"` occurs if the `<xslt>` task doesn't have the Saxon-B library on its classpath. Make sure that the file `saxon9.jar` is in the same directory as the `build.xml` file. Also make sure the following is nested within the `<xslt>` task: `<classpath location="saxon9.jar"/>`

Comment: Sure it is not the case. I  transformation build is successful without this `saxon:parse($fileset-xml)`